# Using Inky (Foundation for Emails) and using custom attributes

Tags: email, zurb-foundation, inky

I need to add some custom attributes into my compiled Foundation for Emails code:

```
<div class="row" customAttribute="value" customAttributeName="value" customAttributeId="value">
```

When I use Inky, I can write code like this:

```
<row class="xyz" customAttribute="value">
```

But it is stripped out of the final compilation. Is there a hint I can add to the code so that it is added back into the dist code?

Answer (score 0):

In the latest release of Foundation for Email (2.2) this should be possible.

> HTML attributes can now be passed to rows and columns thanks to [Brandon Barringer](https://github.com/brandonbarringer) - [commit](https://github.com/zurb/inky/pull/45)

Referenced from here: http://zurb.com/article/1439/foundation-for-emails-2-2-what-a-ruby-gem

The background to the pull request is explained by Brandon [in this discussion](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/44863-add-html-attributes-to-your-inky-markup) with a good example for adding `bgcolor` attribute.

in node_modules/inky/lib/componentFactory.js, towards the bottom you'll see this:

```
// <wrapper>
case this.components.wrapper:
 var classes = ['wrapper'];
      if (element.attr('class')) {
   classes = classes.concat(element.attr('class').split(' '));
 }
 return format('<table class="%s" align="center" ><tr><td class="wrapper-inner">%s</td></tr></table>', classes.join(' '), inner);
```

That builds the tables structure when it sees

Adding in some code to also look for the attribute bgcolor="#XXXXXX". If it finds it, it adds the value into the HTML that it outputs. If it does not find a value, it reverts to the default value from the var, which is bgcolor="". You could also put a value in there if you have a default color.

```
// <wrapper>
case this.components.wrapper:
 var classes = ['wrapper'];
 var bgcolor = ""; // corey add this line
 if (element.attr('class')) {
   classes = classes.concat(element.attr('class').split(' '));
 }
 // corey added the following statement
 if (element.attr('bgcolor')) {
   bgcolor = (element.attr('bgcolor'));
 } // stop new statement

 return format('<table class="%s" align="center" bgcolor="'+bgcolor+'"><tr><td class="wrapper-inner">%s</td></tr></table>', classes.join(' '), inner);
```

The inky markdown can then be written like so:

```
<wrapper bgcolor="#b9cd98">
```